# Vercel build nuxt app failed with flag --standalone

Tags: build, nuxt.js, vercel

Durring deploy [the app](https://github.com/denbon05/en-core) to the **Vercel** there is a build error

```
Build Failed
Command failed with exit code 1: npx nuxt build --standalone 
--no-lock --config-file "nuxt.config.js" /vercel/path0
```

[Maybe this is related to this issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73575842/nuxt-build-locally-but-fails-on-vercel-error-in-node-modules-dev-pathe-dist-in)

When I launch this build command locally, the same error occurs.
In my *[Project settings](https://github.com/denbon05/en-core/blob/main/vercel.json)* I already have predefined build command withoud flags.
[image]

Is it possible to avoid `--standalone` flag? Without this flag application builds just fine.